# I can run an Eclipse project from command line but I cannot run it via Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I built an Eclipse project via `mvn package` and moved the **war** file into *C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\webapps*.
Then, I start Tomcat Server via `startup.bat` and can access it from `http://localhost:8080/myProject` .

On the other hand, when build the project and run it on server in Eclipse, `http://localhost:8080/myProject` give me *HTTP Status 404 - /myProject*

I tried many things but none of them didn't solve the problem.

What I'm missing?

Comment: HOW do you run it from Eclipse on the server? You setup a Tomcat runtime and then drag/drop the project to it? If so, your workspace will have a 'Servers' project added to it which has a server.xml file; Eclipse will put in this file a <Context> element which will tell you what context name your application is deployed under. BUT that may be depending on how you setup the deployment in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You need not give specify the context name, since you are not specifying any context in developement mode.

You have two  options.

Either remove context name and access like

```
 http://localhost:8080
```

Or

If you want to add context, add the file jetty-web-xml  along with your web-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" 
"http://jetty.mortbay.org/configure.dtd"> 
<Configure class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext"> 

      <Set name="contextPath">/myProject </Set>  

</Configure>
```

Comment: I don't understand how I access my project from `http://localhost:8080`. If I run project on server, as far as I know, I have to add context name to access it. Am I wrong?